# Create Silverlight control with JavaScript, but maintain navigation

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a number of Silverlight apps hosted in an ASP.Net Web Forms Application based on the Navigation Application template.  My company has upgraded to IE11 and we are now experiencing the "White Screen of Death" on browser refreshes and after using the Back button.  A lot of searching has me believing that the only way to solve the WSOD is to replace the object tag that I'm using with JavaScript to load it during the onload event of the html body.  While it does appear to fix the WSOD, when I navigate to other pages, the url in the browser does not update, therefore the Back button navigates to the previous web page (not Silverlight page).  It appears the the generated html tag differs a bit - possibly most significantly by the "application/x-silverlight" vs. "application/x-silverlight-2" - I did note that the Silverlight.js file does contain the "-2", so I'm not sure why the output does not use it.

Has anyone dealt with this before and come up with a workaround?

Original code:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost" style="padding:0px;">
        <object id="SilverlightClientControl" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="<%=GetXapLocation()%>"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.60129.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <param name="initparams" id="initParams" runat="server" value="<%=GetInitialParams()%>"/>
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.60129.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>

    </div>
```

Updated JavaScript version (function called in onload event of body tag):

```
function createSL() {
            Silverlight.createObjectEx({
                    source: "<%=GetXapLocation()%>",
                    parentElement: document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost"),
                    id: "SilverlightClientControl",
                    properties: {
                        background: "white",
                        version: "4.0.60129.0",
                        height: "100%",
                        width: "100%"
                    },
                    events: {
                        onError: onSilverlightError
                    },
                    initParams: "<%=GetInitialParams()%>"
                });
        }
```

html generated by object tag:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" id="SilverlightClientControl" data="data:application/x-oleobject;base64,***long string of characters***" 
type="application/x-silverlight-2">
          <param name="source" value="/ClientBin/TicketMaintenance.xap?9/24/2015 3:51:25 PM">
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError">
          <param name="background" value="white">
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.60129.0">
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true">
          <param id="initParams" name="initparams" value="MATaxFreeStartDate=8/15/2015, MATaxFreeEndDate=8/16/2015">
          <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&amp;v=4.0.60129.0">
              <img style="" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376">
          </a>
</object>
```

html generated by the JavaScript:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" id="SilverlightClientControl" data="data:application/x-oleobject;base64,***long string of characters***" 
type="application/x-silverlight">
    <param name="background" value="white">
    <param name="source" value="/ClientBin/TicketMaintenance.xap?9/24/2015 3:51:25 PM">
    <param name="initParams" value="MATaxFreeStartDate=8/15/2015, MATaxFreeEndDate=8/16/2015">
    <param name="onError" value="__slEvent0">
</object>
```